# C# - call Not Successful

Tags: c#, casting

I have the following code

```
 org.pdfclown.objects.PdfDictionary dict = new org.pdfclown.objects.PdfDictionary();
 org.pdfclown.objects.PdfName name;
 name = dict[org.pdfclown.objects.PdfName.AcroForm];
```

what i want to do is to see if the loaded file in the application has got the AcroFrom field i was thinking if i could call

```
 dict[org.pdfclown.objects.PdfName.AcroForm];
```

in some way as the error that comes up now is

```
Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type  
'org.pdfclown.objects.PdfDirectObject' to 'org.pdfclown.objects.PdfName'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) 
C:\ImpressionContext (1)\ImpressionContext\ImpressionContext\ContextDialogue.cs 
184 20  ImpressionContext
```

The original requirement is to detect if the form is AcroForm or if it is an Xfa Form

Is there smeway possible so that i can go to PdfName.AcroForm inside the dictionary and get the value stored in here.

Comment: Your code might be easier to read if you add some using statements at the top of the file, e.g. `using org.pdfclown.objects;`.

Comment: Try making the title of this question better.

Comment: Can't you just cast it with `name = (org.pdfclown.objects.PdfName) dict[org.pdfclown.objects.PdfName.AcroForm]`? BTW, you **REALLY** need to start using `using` statements...

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary here returns `PdfDirectObject`-typed values. What you need to do is cast the returned value to `PdfName`.

```
name = dict[org.pdfclown.objects.PdfName.AcroForm] 
             as org.pdfclown.objects.PdfName;
if(name != null) 
{
    //work with name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `PdfDictionary` returns an `org.pdfclown.objects.PdfDirectObject` object but you want a `org.pdfclown.objects.PdfName` object. So you need to cast it.

You can use:

```
name = dict[org.pdfclown.objects.PdfName.AcroForm] 
          as org.pdfclown.objects.PdfName; // Cast it to PdfName
```